# Why am I getting Error: missing argument: in Contract constructor (count=0, expectedCount=1,... and whats the solution

Tags: solidity, blockchain

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/security/ReentrancyGuard.sol";

contract NFTMarket is ReentrancyGuard {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    Counters.Counter private _itemIds;
    Counters.Counter private _itemsSold;

    address payable owner;
    uint256 listingPrice = 0.025 ether;

    constructor () {
        owner = payable(msg.sender);
    }

    struct MarketItem {
      uint itemId;
      address nftContract;
      uint256 tokenId;
      address payable seller;
      address payable owner;
      uint256 price;
      bool sold;
    }

    mapping(uint256 => MarketItem) private idToMarketItem;

    event MarketItemCreated (
      uint indexed itemId,
      address indexed nftContract,
      uint256 indexed tokenId,
      address seller,
      address owner,
      uint256 price,
      bool sold
    );

    function getListingPrice() public view returns (uint256) {
        return listingPrice;
    }

    function createMarketItem(
        address nftContract,
        uint256 tokenId,
        uint256 price

      ) public payable nonReentrant {
        require(price > 0, "Price must be at least 1 wei");
        require(msg.value == listingPrice, "Price must be equal to listing price");

        _itemIds.increment();
        uint256 itemId = _itemIds.current();

        idToMarketItem[itemId] = MarketItem(
            itemId,
            nftContract,
            tokenId,
            payable(msg.sender),
            payable(address(0)),
            price,
            false
        );

        IERC721(nftContract).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), tokenId);

        emit MarketItemCreated(
            itemId,
            nftContract,
            tokenId,
            msg.sender,
            address(0),
            price,
            false
        );

      }


      function createMarketSale(
          address nftContract,
          uint256 itemId
      ) public payable nonReentrant {
          uint price = idToMarketItem[itemId].price;
          uint tokenId = idToMarketItem[itemId].tokenId;
          require(msg.value == price, "please submit the asking price in order to complete the purchase");

          idToMarketItem[itemId].seller.transfer(msg.value);
          IERC721(nftContract).transferFrom(address(this), msg.sender, tokenId);
          idToMarketItem[itemId].owner = payable(msg.sender);
          idToMarketItem[itemId].sold = true;
          _itemsSold.increment();
          payable(owner).transfer(listingPrice);
      }

     function fetchMarketItems() public view returns (MarketItem[] memory) {
        uint itemCount = _itemIds.current();
        uint unsoldItemCount = _itemIds.current() - _itemsSold.current();
        uint currentIndex = 0;

        MarketItem[] memory items = new MarketItem[](unsoldItemCount);
        for (uint i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
         if (idToMarketItem[i + 1].owner == address(this)) {
           uint currentId = i + 1;
           MarketItem storage currentItem = idToMarketItem[currentId];
           items[currentIndex] = currentItem;
           currentIndex += 1;
         }
        }
        return items;
     }

     function fetchMyNFTs() public view returns (MarketItem[] memory) {
      uint totalItemCount = _itemIds.current();
      uint itemCount = 0;
      uint currentIndex = 0;

      for (uint i = 0; i < totalItemCount; i++) {
        if (idToMarketItem[i + 1].owner == msg.sender) {
          itemCount += 1;
        }
      }

       MarketItem[] memory items = new MarketItem[](itemCount);
       for (uint i = 0; i < totalItemCount; i++) {
        if (idToMarketItem[i + 1].owner == msg.sender) {
           uint currentId = i + 1;
           MarketItem storage currentItem = idToMarketItem[currentId];
           items[currentIndex] = currentItem;
           currentIndex += 1;
        }
       }
      return items;
    }

    function fetchItemsCreated() public view returns (MarketItem[] memory) {
      uint totalItemCount = _itemIds.current();
      uint itemCount = 0;
      uint currentIndex = 0;

      for (uint i = 0; i < totalItemCount; i++) {
        if (idToMarketItem[i + 1].seller == msg.sender) {
          itemCount += 1;
        }
      }

      MarketItem[] memory items = new MarketItem[](itemCount);
      for (uint i = 0; i < totalItemCount; i++) {
        if (idToMarketItem[i + 1].seller == msg.sender) {
          uint currentId = i + 1;
          MarketItem storage currentItem = idToMarketItem[currentId];
          items[currentIndex] = currentItem;
          currentIndex += 1;
        }
      }
      return items;
    }
}
```

Comment: ```Error: missing argument:  in Contract constructor (count=0, expectedCount=1, code=MISSING_ARGUMENT, version=contracts/5.6.0)```    THATS THE ERROR IT BRINGS

Comment: Please, can you clarify your issue?

Comment: i am currently working on a nft project, so i tried running the test but keep getting the error ``` Error: missing argument:  in Contract constructor (count=0, expectedCount=1, code=MISSING_ARGUMENT, version=contra.6.0)``` anytime i type npx hardhat test

Comment: @IyodoMichael The error isn't in the contract, but it seems to be in the deployment scripts. Can you provide them?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried passing in an argument in your deploy script?

it's requesting that you pass in one from your constructor in your contract. i just had this issue 5 minutes ago and this was what i did

```
const contractName = await contractNameFactory.deploy(1);
  console.log("success");
```

The argument 1 is what's missing. Use console.log to know if it checks past that line which it should now.

Answer (score 0):

You could also insert "1" in `token = await TokenFactory.deploy(1);`  as below...

```
describe("BCToken", () => {
    let token;

    beforeEach(async () => {
        const TokenFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory("BCToken");
        token = await TokenFactory.deploy(1);
```

Answer (score -1):

It's because you are importing the ERC721.sol contract which requires constructor parameters "name" and "symbol". So you should either remove that import if it's unnecessary or add the parameters to this contract's constructor. `constructor () ERC721("My Collection", "MNFT"){ owner = payable(msg.sender); }`

Comment: That's not correct it doesn't inherit from ERC721. It merely includes is for interacting with tokens.